# Deriving $E[X]$ and $Var(X)$ of a binomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to derive the expectation value $E[X]$ and variance $Var(X)$ of a binomial distribution for the random variable $X$ with $X \backsim B(n,p)$.

I know that $E[X] = \sum_\limits{i=0}^n x_ip_i$ and $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$, but don't know how to start with it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: Start by looking at the bernouli distribution.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, depending on what you've already studied. With no attempt on your part, it's really difficult to know how to give a helpful answer. Do you understand the derivation of $E(X)$ in @Did's link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it's easier to solve this when you think of the binomial distribution as the sum of iid Bernoulli trials. So $X = Y_1 + \ldots Y_n$ with $Y_i \sim \operatorname{Ber}(p)$. Then $$E[X] = E\left[Y_1 + \ldots +Y_n \right] = E[Y_1] + \ldots + E[Y_n] = p + \ldots + p = np$$

Replace $E[\cdot]$ with $\operatorname{Var}(\cdot)$ and the same thing happens again.

Comment: @Henry $E(X^2)=np$ for $X$ binomial $(n,p)$? Sure about that?

Comment: @Did Apparently not.  $E[Y_i^2]=p$ again (so $\operatorname{Var}(Y_1)=p-p^2$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X)=n(p-p^2)$) while $E[Y_iY_j]=p^2$ when $i \not= j$ so $E[X^2]=np + n(n-1)p^2$